# How to use function from static library if I don't have header file

Tags: c++, c, static-libraries

Is it a way to use function from static lib, if I don't have header file, only *.a file, but I know function signature?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, if you know the function signature

Just write the function signature before calling it, as:

```
void f(int); //it is as if you've included a header file

//then call it
f(100);
```

All you need to do is : link the `slib.a` to the program.

Also, remember that, if the static library is written in C and has been compiled with C compiler, then you've to use `extern "C"` when writing the function signature (if you program in C++), as:

```
extern "C" void f(int); //it is as if you've included a header file

//then call it
f(100);
```

Alternatively, if you've many functions, then you can group them together as:

```
extern "C" 
{
   void f(int); 
   void g(int, int); 
   void h(int, const char*);
}
```

You may prefer writing all the function signatures in a namespace so as to avoid any possible name-collisions:

```
namespace capi
{
  extern "C" 
  {
    void f(int); 
    void g(int, int); 
    void h(int, const char*);
  } 
}

//use them as:

capi::f(100); 
capi::g(100,200); 
capi::h(100,200, "string");
```

Now you can write all these in a header file so that you could include the header file in your `.cpp` files (as usual), and call the function(s) (as usual).

Hope that helps.

Comment: In other words: Write the header file for the library yourself.

Comment: How about calling classes and their member functions? I am facing similar situation but the functions I need are defined as members of a specific class defined in a .lib file. And I do know all the signatures.

Comment: @DCoder: The members are non-static functions? If so, then it might have data members as well, with a layout which not known to your compilers. In short, your scenario is difficult, and you have to look for, or ask the developers of the lib to expose the class.

Answer (score 5):

The easiest way: Write the signature in a header file, include it and link against the library.